# Share roxygen2 entries between scripts

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am currently developping a package containing several algorithms for doing the same thing (extreme probability estimation btw). In this scope, a lot of function share the same inputs, and handle them the same way.

Is there a way to avoid copy/paste each field from on file to another (eg @note @references ...) ? Or where should I write these shared features ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. You could group these functions on the same help page if they logically belong together, by setting `@rdname` on all but one entry:

   ```
   #' Description
   #' @param x this is an interesting argument
   foo = function (x) x * 2

   #' @rdname foo
   bar = function (x) x * 3
   ```
2. You can use `@inheritParams` to “inherit” the parameters of one function in the documentation block of another function.

   ```
   #' Description
   #' @param x this is an interesting argument
   foo = function (x) x * 2

   #' Description
   #' @inheritParams foo
   bar = function (x) x * 3
   ```